# Compiler can't find SDL headers?

Tags: c++, sdl

I downloaded the SDL .zip files and added the added the "include" files as necessary. When I went to run the example that had been pre-made by Code::Blocks, an error occured that said "SDL/SDL.h: No file or directory". Any help? Code below:

```
ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
// initialize SDL video
if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    return 1;
}

// make sure SDL cleans up before exit
atexit(SDL_Quit);

// create a new window
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 16,
                                       SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
if ( !screen )
{
    printf("Unable to set 640x480 video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}

// load an image
SDL_Surface* bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("cb.bmp");
if (!bmp)
{
    printf("Unable to load bitmap: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
}

// centre the bitmap on screen
SDL_Rect dstrect;
dstrect.x = (screen->w - bmp->w) / 2;
dstrect.y = (screen->h - bmp->h) / 2;

// program main loop
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    // message processing loop
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        // check for messages
        switch (event.type)
        {
            // exit if the window is closed
        case SDL_QUIT:
            done = true;
            break;

            // check for keypresses
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            {
                // exit if ESCAPE is pressed
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    done = true;
                break;
            }
        } // end switch
    } // end of message processing

    // DRAWING STARTS HERE

    // clear screen
    SDL_FillRect(screen, 0, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0));

    // draw bitmap
    SDL_BlitSurface(bmp, 0, screen, &dstrect);

    // DRAWING ENDS HERE

    // finally, update the screen :)
    SDL_Flip(screen);
} // end main loop

// free loaded bitmap
SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);

// all is well ;)
printf("Exited cleanly\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't set your include directories correctly.

Comment: this is a compiler error  so the compiler cant find the SDL.h file. therefore add the directory to the 
Project -> Build options -> Directories -> Compiler
list of directories where the compiler should search for files

Comment: FWIW, the Nuwen distro of g++ includes SDL (and Boost), and is small and nice. It has a configuration batch file that sets up things right. I'm assuming Windows since you're using a .bmp file.

Comment: If you are using SDL2.0, make sure to include SDL2\SDL.h and not SDL\SDL.h